# How I can remove the Play-Button in statusbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

is it possible to remove the play button in the statusbar if I play an soundfile but the app is in backgroundmode and I see the springboard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsxLl.png

regards Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can not change the icon of the status bar . but we can hidden the status bar of the Application

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

Comment: Hmm that's a good idea, but the app is in background mode, I pressed the home button and see the springboard :(

Answer (score 0):

try running the audio in `ambient` mode.

Comment: Okay, but I have seen, that apple reject the distribution process, if you are playing silent musik, to run the app continue :(